# How can I specify the sort order of Enum values in the control manifest of a PCF component?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Let's assume having the following `size` property of type `Enum` in the `ControlManifest.Input.xml` of a PCF component (Microsoft Power Apps component framework):

```xml
    <property name="size" display-name-key="size" of-type="Enum" usage="input" default-value="48">
      <value name="10">10</value>
      <value name="36">36</value>
      <value name="100">100</value>
    </property>
```

When used in a canvas App, the order of the values in the combobox for selecting the value of the property seems to be always in alphabetic order:

```
10
100
36
```

Is there any way to declare a different order?

The documentation doesn't mention the value tag at all:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/component-framework/manifest-schema-reference/property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found so far is to pad the name with zeros:

```xml
    <property name="size" display-name-key="size" of-type="Enum" usage="input" default-value="48">
      <value name="010">10</value>
      <value name="036">36</value>
      <value name="100">100</value>
    </property>
```

This will let the values appear in the correct order:

```
10
36
100
```

I can even give them a more specific display name while keeping the correct order:

```xml
    <property name="size" display-name-key="size" of-type="Enum" usage="input" default-value="48">
      <value name="010" display-name-key="10px">10</value>
      <value name="036" display-name-key="36px">36</value>
      <value name="100" display-name-key="100px">100</value>
    </property>
```

The only draw-back is that, as you can see on the advanced property editing tab, the selected value is stored with leading zeros:

```
'NAMESPACE.ComponentName.PropertyName'.'010'
'NAMESPACE.ComponentName.PropertyName'.'036'
'NAMESPACE.ComponentName.PropertyName'.'100'
```

It might be a matter of personal taste that I don't like this representation of the values. So far I can't find any draw-back caused by the leading zeros, it just doesn't feel right for my developers heart.